# Border ignores an element

Tags: css

Ok so i have text inside a border that's inside a bigger border. The text inside the border is in a row of 2 but the problem is the larger border doesn't go around them. Here's a picture.[image]

The problem i'm pretty sure is either the width or the float of the inside border which makes it a row.
Here is the css:

```
.fifty {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
}
```

Here is the css for the actual border:

```
.newspaper3 {
border-top: 3px solid #EEEEEE;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
border-left: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
border-right: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
padding: 5px;
margin-right: 3px;
}
```

Here's part of the html:

```
<div class="count">
<div class="fifty">
<div class="newspaper3">
text
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's all the html and css http://jsfiddle.net/ELSaV/
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you show us your HTML structure as well ?

Comment: add <div style="clear:both;"></div> after your .fifty element.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Hmm that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g3U9v/2/ doesn't have any problem: The problem seems to be the element displayed before. Put the <div style="clear: both;"></div> before the <div class="count">, it should be ok after (setting in the css file .count { clear: both; } would work if the <div style="clear: both;"><div> works) .

Comment: That stacked them on top of each other instead of beside. I will put the whole page and all the css on jsfiddle, one sec.

Comment: Ok here  is all the css and html.http://jsfiddle.net/ELSaV/

Comment: just add to your CSS `.count{ clear:both; }` that will fix the problem for your left float

Comment: @DrixsonOseña This stacks them on top of each other instead of beside each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/ELSaV/4/

Basically your issue is caused by the `float: left` CSS attribute on the `.fifty` element. Using the `float` attribute removes the element from the actual document flow, so its position is ignored by other elements.

To reassign its position to the document flow, you should add an element that has a `clear` attribute after the one that has the  `float` attribute. This `clear` should have the value which you wish to clear. In this case it should be `left`, but in case you need to reuse this element later in your project, you should create a class that clears `both`.

So, to solve your problem, and reassign `.fifty` to the document flow I created an empty `div` element with a class name `.clear`, and in the CSS I attributed this class a `clear: both`.

```
.clear { 
   clear: both;
}
```

In order for `.fifty` children to be displayed in a row, you simply need to assign them the same `float` attribute, which pushes them in the same direction, forcing their alignment within the parent element.

```
.newspaper3 {
    border-top: 3px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-left: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-right: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    float:left; /* ADD THIS */
}
```

*Note: as I said I just attributed the value of `both` to this `clear` element, because I am assuming you could need it later in your project, although, in this case, you only need to clear the `left` float. There are other ways of establishing a `clear` on your floats, this is just one strategy.*

Comment: Ok this works except now they are on top of each other rather than in a row.

Comment: What needs to be on a row? You only have single elements here, nothing to be shown side by side I guess

Comment: Oh sorry i guess i didn't add it to jsfiddle. The picture in the question shows. .fifty is floated left so they will be beside each other.

Comment: What elements do you need side by side. I will update my answer with the full explanation

Comment: Exactly how you just did it.